# File.Exists не находит существующий файл (C# WinForms (win10))

Tags: файлы, поиск, файловая-система, проект

Не менял настроек проекта, в одном проекте переменная "j" возвращает true в другом false! Голова кругом( прежде работало. В чем может быть проблема?

Boolean j = File.Exists("C:\Users\JPJP\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SoundAlarm\SoundAlarm\bin\Debug\Log\ExUpdate\1.txt");

Answer (score 0):

Возможно недостаточно разрешений на чтение файла.

File.Exist возвращает значение true, если вызывающий оператор имеет требуемые разрешения и path содержит имя существующего файла; в противном случае — false. Этот метод также возвращает false, если path — null, недействительный путь или строка нулевой длины. **Если у вызывающего оператора нет достаточных полномочий на чтение заданного файла**, исключения не создаются, а данный метод **возвращает false** вне зависимости от существования path.

Comment: Действительно "..нет достаточных полномочий" ). Выяснил для себя что Comodo по тихой включается (после вырубания через диспетчер задач) и не дает новому приложению, которое только что откомпилировано и не добавлено в доверенные, работать с файлами, тем самым возвращает false хоть даже файл и есть на диске. Может начинающим сэкономит пару минут на отладке.